# Replacing Javascript with Python

Tags: javascript, python, web

Is it possible to make a website using HTML/CSS with *Python* instead of *JavaScript*?

Comment: Do you mean a web whit any piece of javascript .js ? What kind of web are you developing?

Comment: Depends what you were using the JavaScript for.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean on the backend, yes, of course. see [flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/) and [django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) projects.

Answer (score 1):

Python in any way could be a replacement of javascript and and vice versa.

If your web don't need a visual effects, don't need data from Rest Apis, is just and html with css, the answer is: **You could create the html in the server using python**

If you web need a lot the classic effects, open/close popups, left hamburger menu and more complex features in the client side (browser), the answer is: **No, you can't develop it without javascript**

There attempts to create a web effects with pure css, but is not common.

### Server Rendering vs Client side Rendering

In web development there are two approaches to deliver content to end users: [Server rendering and client side rendering](https://medium.com/@benjburkholder/javascript-seo-server-side-rendering-vs-client-side-rendering-bc06b8ca2383)

**Server side rendering (SSR)** — the traditional rendering method, basically all of your page’s resources are housed on the server. Then, when the page is requested (commonly from web browsers), the Html, JS and CSS are downloaded. Also frameworks can dynamically can create the html based on backend logic and finally download it. At this point, a lot of frameworks offer wonders for creating apps in no time with "amazing" functionalities.

Technologies : java, c#, python, nodejs, etc

**Client side rendering (CSR)** — Which is sometimes called "Frontend rendering" is a more recent kind of rendering method, this relies on JS executed on the client side (browser) via a JavaScript framework. So, when page is requested, a minimal , little or empty index.html, css and js were downloaded. Here **javascript** is responsible to send or receive data and update a minimal section of the page **without an entire page refresh.**. Finally when user click or trigger some event, javascript will send or receive the **data** commonly to an api rest (json) using an async call ([ajax](https://medium.com/letsboot/basics-using-ajax-with-fetch-api-b2218b0b9691)).

This is the most used currently in companies around the world and a required skill in any web developer.

Technologies : react, angular, vue, aurelia, jquery, pure javascript, etc

Answer (score 0):

yes. js can be useful for ajax calls back to your python server. But you can hide that nowadays with things like htmx.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is quite complex. You should learn how a browser works. In a broad perspective it's like this:

1. browser resolves the URL, retrieves the html response from there
2. browser retrieves all the other files listed in the main html (CSS, script files, images, etc)
3. browser interprets the html structure and the CSS for displaying in the window
4. browser interprets and executes the script files using the ECMAScript engine (basically a JavaScript interpreter)

That last step adds interactivity to the html by dynamically updating the html and CSS. From what I found, all browsers use a JavaScript interpreter for this job. It's entirely possible to use a different interpreter like CPython (for python) to execute python scripts the same way as JavaScript.

Until now, I think, there is not such a browser that offers a python interpreter. But you could try to build one. Many developers would thank you for offering an alternative to the god forsaken JavaScript language.